# How do I make a loop inside a method in one class to call on another method in another class n Java?

Tags: java, loops, methods, instance-variables

I have a method in class `Employee` called `calculatePay` that does calculations for certain pay and taxes.

```
public void calculatePay() {

    totalHoursWorked = 0;
    grossPay = 0;
    fedTax = 0;
    stateTax = 0;
    netPay = 0;
    totalTax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getNoTimeCards(); i++) {

        TimeCard timeCard = getTimeCard(i);

        totalHoursWorked += timeCard.getHoursWorked();

    }

    grossPay = totalHoursWorked * payRate;

    if (grossPay >= 200) {

        fedTax = (grossPay - 200) * .1;

    } else {

        fedTax = 0;

    }

    stateTax = grossPay * .04;

    totalTax = fedTax + stateTax;

    netPay = grossPay - totalTax;

}
```

I need to create a method called `calculatePay` in another class called `Company`. In this method, I need to create a loop that calls on the `calculatePay` method in `Employee`. Is calling on a method in a loop any different than calling on an instance variable? Whatever I try doesn't seem to work. Here's what `i` currently have for the method in `Company`:

```
public void calculatePay() {
    for (int i = 0; i < noEmployees; i++) {
        Employee employee = getEmployee(i);
        employee.calculatePay(); {
            return;
        }

}
}
```

Any help in explaining would be great.

Comment: You have a weird `{ return; }` block in your method . Try to fix your indentation, you will see these kind of problems easier .

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: your code makes no sense. why do you have a return statement in that loop? that shouldn't be there. sure, you call the method correctly, but since it doesn't return anything: what do you expect to get?

Comment: I think the key issue here is you don't know the syntax for returning values from a method.  The [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorials would be a good starting point (specifically, the one dealing with [return values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)).

Comment: What isn't working is that i need to call the calculatePay method so when I call on the instance variables, calculated in calculatePay, in my print method, it will show the results instead of 0.

Comment: So the return statement shouldn't be there but what else is really wrong?

Comment: Your loop is essentially `for(int i = 0; i < noEmployees; i++) {getEmployee(i).calculatePay(); }`. This will run `calculatePay()` of all employees. Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to make the method loop over all of the employees calling calculatePay on each employee

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I see what you tried to do.

So you tried creating a function, then tried to make it return it's calculated value by using the parentheses when calling it, didn't you? However, that isn't how Java syntax works.

`calculatePay()` in `Employee` is a void function, meaning it won't return any value. In this case, you want to have it return the `netPay` of type `double`. So instead, you should define the function as:

```
public double calculatePay() {
    // code
    netPay = grossPay - totalTax;
    return netPay;
}
```

And in `Company` you would just do

```
public  calculatePay() {
    for (int i = 0; i < noEmployees; i++) {
        Employee employee = getEmployee(i);
        System.out.println(employee.calculatePay());
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind this code is incomplete. If you also want `calculatePay()` in `Company` to return the total value or something, you would also need to change it's return type to `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what i am trying to do is make make the method loop over all of the employees calling `calculatePay` on each employee. So when i try `System.out.printf("Hours Worked:                       %d%n", employee.getTotalHoursWorked());` in my print method, i get the result instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should have two lists, one of employees and other of time cards.

```
public void calculatePay() 
{
    ...
   totalHoursWorked = getHoursWorked();
    ...
}

public void calculateEmployeesPay() 
{
    for(final Employee emp : EmployeeList)
    {
       emp.calculatePay(); 
    }
}

public double getHoursWorked()
{ 
    double totalHoursWorked = 0.0;

    for (final TimeCard tc : TimeCardList)
    {
        totalHoursWorked += tc.getHoursWorked();
    }
    return totalHoursWorked;
}
```

if calculatePay() is void then netPay must changed to be an instance variable instead of a local.